# kafka server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request

Tags: apache-kafka

In partion re-assginment,that is still showing in progress.

Ref used gist  https://gist.github.com/ralph-tice/bc8f66c4fe1d4238ce54c54272fc4ba2.
After this continuous getting error in Kafka server log.

```
ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-101]: Error for partition [test,22] to broker 101:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread
```